# Drawing a pyramid in console application

Tags: vb.net

How can i write a program that asks the user to enter the number of lines for the pyramid to be drawn. If I typed number 6 the pyramid will have 6 star from the bottom to the top.

Comment: Mr. GH15, your question strikes me as odd. Are you describing a 2D triangle or a 3D pyramid? Does this 3D pyramid have a triangular or rhomboid base? What is the orientation of the pyramid (point up or down)? What do these stars look like? Please answer these questions so I can assist you further with your homework.

Comment: Your question lack details, Mr. Gh. Is it the one like in Egypt?

Comment: Also you forgot to tell us how many slaves it requires..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want it 2d pyramid in the console window

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the given number into int type and then perform several iterations accordingly, each iteration you need to print blanks and starts.

So the base line will be the users' input, from now on, you need to subtract one from stars and add one to blanks on each loop and print it to the console:)